# how to use linq to get memory location?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I am trying to find a particular element and then I want to edit that element.

```
storage.First(item => item.dirty == true).dirty = false;
```

However this doesn't appear to work since I am guessing First is creating another list and populating it. Is there a function to do what I am I am trying to do?

Here is the data type I am using:

```
class BaseRegister {
  public bool dirty {set;get;}
}

List <BaseRegister> storage = new List <BaseRegister> ();
```

Comment: is `item` a value or reference type?

Comment: Item is a class with a property called dirty, but when I try the above line dirty is still true

Comment: @SamFisher83 How are you checking dirty the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something else wrong with your program which is confusing you. For the avoidance of doubt, here is a complete program using your data types. The output is:

```
---Before---
True
False
True
---After---
False
False
True
```

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication40 {
  internal class Program {
    private static List<BaseRegister> storage=new List<BaseRegister>();

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
      storage.Add(new BaseRegister {dirty=true});
      storage.Add(new BaseRegister {dirty=false});
      storage.Add(new BaseRegister {dirty=true});
      Dump("---Before---");
      storage.First(item => item.dirty==true).dirty=false;
      Dump("---After---");
    }

    private static void Dump(string title) {
      Debug.WriteLine(title);
      foreach(var br in storage) {
        Debug.WriteLine(br.dirty);
      }
    }

    private class BaseRegister {
      public bool dirty { set; get; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you are right. It looks like it was the IDE not updating the variable correctly in the watchlist, but it was actually changing it.

Answer (score 4):

This will work, but only if your type (that contains `.dirty`) is a class.

If this is a struct, you will not be able to mutate the struct this way.  With a struct, you'd need to replace the entire struct in the collection, which is very difficult using the LINQ extensions, as they are designed for queries, not edits.

If the type (of `storage`) implements `IList<T>`, such as `List<YourClass>`, you could use:

```
int index = storage.FindIndex(item => item.dirty);
var item = storage[index];
item.dirty = false;
storage[index] = item;
```

Note that it's messy, but mostly because it has to completely reset the value of the struct in the list.

This, btw, is partly why mutable structs are a bad idea.  If you find that this is a pattern you think you need with your type, you may want to consider a class.  In general, any item that's going to have a "dirty" flag is likely mutable, and as such, should be a class and not a struct.

Comment: I am not using a struct it is a class.                                Class BaseRegister {
  bool dirty {set;get;}
}

Answer (score 0):

If item is a reference type, this should change the `dirty` property/field.

If item is a value type, `First` returns a copy, and this should not even compile.

First is not creating a list, it returns the first item in the sequence that fulfills the condition.